# How to identify burnt out component

Tags: identification, components, remote-control

My sons birthday present literally went up in smoke when batteries were inserted. I will eventually get a replacement but it will take time and I'd love to be able to fix this as soon as possible. It's a radio controller for a car. It's fairly evident which component has burnt out (not so much if there's other damage), but the burn has made most of the identifying numbers/letters impossible to read. There are no components with the same package on the circuit board to serve as inspiration for what this one might have been.

From the size of the component I am pretty positive it's a SOT89 package but that's where my detective skills end, none of the markings help me figure out what this chip is/was, any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Close up picture of burnt out component]

Edit: Addition of picture of full circuit board, component is dead center in the picture, although upside down.
[image: Full circuit board]

Comment: The `/33` and the connections suggest a 3V3 regulator. Can you get a slightly zoomed out image as clear as this one?

Comment: While the photo is sharp, it would help to see more of the surroundings to get an idea what that could be. Like what other nearby components it connects to. Also bear in mind that the problem such as a short circuit can be elsewhere in the circuit, and the replacement part would also burn up if the actual problen is not fixed.

Comment: ...so that we can see more of the writing on the board and nearby components?

Comment: Test the resistance between the right-most pin (output?) and ground -- a short to the 3V3 rail would kill the regulator fast (like it seems happened).

Comment: Resistance between the negative battery pin (left one in the full overview picture) and the right pin on the crispy circuit (left as seen in the overview) is 22.5 ohm, not sure if that qualifies as a short or not.

Comment: When batteries were inserted, in what state was the on/off switch? It looks like the burnt part gets power on ON position, and lets battery charge in OFF position. Also, were batteries inserted with correct polarity? There seems to be no protection for reverse polarity.

Comment: First of all, let me just say how impressed I am by all who've commented. Being a programmer, electronics is not the stack exchange section I usually hang around at. My hat's off to you.

Comment: My memory of the exact chain of events is not perfect. I think the batteries were inserted with switch=Off smoke might have happened when I turned it on but I'm not sure. Polarity should have been correct and if it wasn't there's a physical polarity protection of sorts in the battery lid out of picture, the circuit shouldn't have been closed if all the batteries were consistently the wrong way around. 3 out of 4 could in theory have been wrong and the polarity protection could have been bypassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bite late but I thought I would close this thread. Some of the comments were spot on! I received a new replacement unit a while ago, the picture is of the undamaged component in the new radio.
[image: 6206A]

Knowing now what sort of component I was looking for I went searching on various scrap electronics I had laying around. On an old non-functional AM2 motherboard I found a L1087 component that to my layman eyes seemed like it might be an OK replacement. Since the old radio was broken and I had a new working I figured I could at most make the broke a little more broken.

Soldering the L1087 in place of the burnt 6206A was a success so most likely nothing else was broken and I now have a spare radio if the kids break one.